# Redis Cloud doesn't exist in Azure Marketplace

Tags: azure, redis, azure-marketplace

I wanted to create a "Redis Cloud" via the Azure marketplace but I didn't found this service in the marketplace list.
Doesn't it exist anymore? Why?
Or is there some kind of limitation, e.g. it's only available for certain types of Azure subscriptions?

I'm wondering because via redislabs.com I can still choose "Azure" for creating a Redis Cloud - but not via Azure marketplace.

Comment: since it is offered as a Managed cache service I believe azure team might have removed it. But again you can run your own redis service in an IaaS VM .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you are right Munchkin.

I've looked into the matter and it appears that our Redis Cloud plugin is stuck in limbo between the old and new portals. This is an Azure team issue and we're waiting for a resolution from them.

Until this is rectified, note that you can always create a direct subscription via our website however and do feel free to contact our [support team](https://redislabs.com/support) with any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the "New Portal" Azure Marketplace, http://portal.azure.com. There you should be able to find it listed as "Redis Cache" or Redis Cloud, first one is Managed by Microsoft, the second one is IaaS on a VM.

[image: Azure Screenshot]

Comment: I explicitly asked for "Redis Cloud". Yes, it is listed in the new portal, but when I click on it I only get a redirect to the Classic portal - and there it is not listed (anymore).